# Failed to deploy Azure Functions (Python) with Bicep "Error: LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy Azure Functions (Python3.11) using the following Bicep.

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'samplestorage123'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'testplan'
  location: location
  kind: 'linux'
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'testfunc'
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    reserved: true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'python'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: 'func001'
        }
      ]
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: [
          'https://portal.azure.com'
        ]
      }
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      pythonVersion: '3.11'
      linuxFxVersion: 'Python|3.11'
    }
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: null
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}
```

But the deployment fails with the following error:

```
The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.
```

As a test, if I erase the "linuxFxVersion" field, the deployment will succeed. However, when I browse the Azure Portal, I get the error message "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found."

[image: Azure Portal Error Message]

Naturally, accessing the site results in an error.

[image]

Could someone please provide a bicep template for a successful Python Function?

Comment: What is the value that you are passing? @tekunikaruza

Comment: "location" parameter is "japanwest".

Comment: Sorry. Some parameters were not defined, so I replaced them with hard coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531787/19785512) worked by me earlier, I have modified your bicep code as below and the deployment was successful without any issues.

```bash
param  name  string = 'jahnavistoragesceoo'
param  location  string = 'EastUS'
resource  storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' = {
name: name
location: location
sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
}
kind: 'StorageV2'
}
resource  applicationInsights  'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
name: 'nameapplication-insights'
location: location
kind: 'web'
properties: {
   Application_Type: 'web'
   Request_Source: 'rest'
   }
}
resource  hostingPlan  'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' = {
name: name
location: location
kind: 'Linux'
sku: {
   name: 'Y1'
   tier: 'Dynamic'
}
properties: {
   reserved: true
  } 
}
resource  functionApp  'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
name: name
location: location
kind: 'functionapp'
identity: {
   type: 'SystemAssigned'
}
properties: {
serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
siteConfig: {
  pythonVersion: '3.11'
  linuxFxVersion: 'python|3.11'
  appSettings: [
    {
      name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
      value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
    }
    {
      name: 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT' 
      value: 'true'
    }
    {
      name: 'ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD'  
      value: 'true'
    }
    {
      name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
      value: '~4'
    }
    {
      name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
      value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
    }
    {
      name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
      value: 'python'
    }
  ]
}
    httpsOnly: true
   }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I checked the difference with you. In `hostingPlan`,  `reserved: true` could not be specified. For Linux, it must be set to `true`. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#appserviceplanproperties )