# Terraform azurerm_linux_function_app doesn't support python version 3.10

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to deploy a python azure function to azure and I'm not able to do it with version 3.10, If I use version 3.9 it works.
The weird thing is that Azure supports version 3.10, [Terraform says it supports version 3.10](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app). So what's the mistake?

**ERROR**

```
**Error: expected site_config.0.application_stack.0.python_version to be one of [3.9 3.8 3.7], got 3.10
│ 
│   with azurerm_linux_function_app.fn_analytics,
│   on python_analytics_functions.tf line 65, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fn_analytics": 
│   65:       python_version = "3.10"**
```

**Scripts**

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp_analytics" {
  name                = "<funct plan name>"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fn_analytics" {
  name                       = "<func name>"
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.safn.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.safn.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.asp_analytics.id

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
      ...
  }
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the terraform runtime version you are using in your environment. @Nelssen

Comment: This is the recent [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78101442/19785512) worked by me with Python 3.11 version with upgraded terraform and its provider. @Nelssen

Comment: I have terraform v1.7.4
but noticed the azurerm is v3.33.0. I'll try the version 3.96.0 as you used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very transient issue which is related to the versions of terraform providers.

Run `terraform init -upgrade` to avoid the version conflicts.

Alternatively, you can use latest release of [azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) provider version by adding below block directly in your terraform code.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.96.0"
    }
  }
}
```

*I have tried below code in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully as shown.*

*Note*: If you are running code in Azure CLI, check the version of it and upgrade it to the latest one using `az upgrade` command.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.96.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
  name = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "linuxfunctionappsa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp_analytics" {
  name                = "myplanj"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fn_analytics" {
  name                       = "latestfuncj"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.asp_analytics.id

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
  }
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: good stuff buddy, looking forward to try that out and get back to you. probably later today